# Is there something like GitHub for quantum programming?

Tags: programming

I'm just learning about quantum computer but some of it has been available for people to research & practice so I'd like to study it myself. The only kind of quantum computing I found so far is IBM cloud service and Q# quantum simulator but the sources and examples are limited, and I only found a bunch of display emoji & a card-guessing mini-game in quantum programming. Are there any main sources like GitHub but for quantum computing programming?

Comment: You might wanna check out this list of quantum programming projects: https://github.com/markf94/os_quantum_software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for algorithms to look through, or programs for an actual quantum computer?

If the former the [IBM Q Experience](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/tutorial?sectionId=full-user-guide&page=introduction) user guide has good explanations of some of them, and other questions you can find on this Stack Exchange can get you to more algorithms.

If you are looking for programs to be run on a quantum computer like IBM's cloud offerings, I'm not sure if there is a github specific to is, but looking into the [Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorial) github would be a good place to start!

Comment: thanks, mostly just source code, i try to program some of my own app like a calculator or search algorithim to run on IBM quantum computer. May i ask one more question? does ibm quantum computer really powerful? i mean no need as powerful as a supercomputer, i always expected it to be at least stronger than my school's server

Comment: @QuanLee No current device is more powerful than your school's server. Or even your phone. They are initial prototypes that can be used for testing.

Answer (score 6):

For Q#, the largest GitHub repositories of algorithms written in Q# are the official [libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumLibraries/) and [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/) repos.

If you want to start studying Q# by writing small quantum computing programs, there is [Quantum Katas repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas), it has less code and the code is simpler but it aims specifically to teach the basics.

Comment: Do microsoft have any available quantum cloud service at the moment? i only find simulator for Q# & google are developing one, i just don't know when will they release it

Comment: No, Microsoft doesn't have a public quantum cloud service at the moment. You can simulate 30-ish qubits with Q# on a desktop computer, which allows to run a lot of educational programs.

Answer (score 5):

There is no GitHub like service dedicated to quantum programming. It is all on standard GitHub.

Most useful examples are on the repositories for the quantum SDKs (IBM's [QISKit](https://github.com/Qiskit), [Rigetti's Forest](https://github.com/rigetticomputing), Microsoft's [Q#](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum), Google's [Cirq](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq), and [ProjectQ](https://github.com/projectq-framework)).

For QISKit, the tutorial has quite a large number of examples. Beyond the simple 'Hello World' example, most resources are found in the [reference](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorial/tree/master/reference) folder.

You'll also find things scattered around on the pages of single GitHub users. To find these, you could try looking at who has forked the SDKs or participated in quantum hackathons.